# aspell not working on mac - mountain lion, needed as guiguts plugin

Tags: macos, terminal, aspell

When typing aspell in the command line as a normal user, I get the following error message.

```
aspell
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libaspell.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/aspell
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/lib/libaspell.15.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
/usr/local/lib/libaspell.15.dylib: stat() failed with errno=13
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

However, as root, I do not get this error.

When using guiguts from command line as normal user, I do not get an error message, but as root I get the following:

```
Guiguts 1.0.23: If you have any problems, please include any error messages that appear
here with your bug report.
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".
```

What do I do to get aspell to work?

I tried to navigate to /usr/local/lib but was unable as a normal user. However, as root I can see that the libaspell.15.dylib file is there.

Comment: Well it appears there was a permissions issue. For some reason the _libaspell.15.dylib_ file was not global readable. After changing the permissions I had to reinstall the dictionaries. Then everything worked normally.